# How to rubberband zoom w/o the shift key: arcgis api for javascript

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to enable the rubberband zoom effect without users having to hold the shift key down.  This behavior is found is Esri navigation bar dijit.  I don't want to use the dijit.

How can I get a zoom in/out bounding box to draw without forcing users to use shift key?

Comment: How will you distinguish between this and panning?

Comment: i would have buttons on a nav bar that the user could use to toggle between them.  i just want to build a custom nav bar.

Answer (score 1):

I completely misread the docs.  Here is the solution:

The zoom in/out is handled by the [navigation class](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/navigation-amd.html).  This includes the ability to draw a rubberband box.  You can design your own toolbar, you just need the navigation object in your code.

Add to the top of js:

```
dojo.require("esri.toolbars.navigation");
var navToolbar;
```

Add to the init function:

```
navToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Navigation(map);
```

Create a listener for the button of your choice, and include this:

```
navToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Navigation(map);
```